# Draw Text with stencil buffer

Tags: text, directx, slimdx, directx-10, stencil-buffer

I set up the stencil buffer so only parts of the screen are affected by draw calls. Specifically, I want to draw into a small area. It will become an UI, so everything drawn will be some kind of 2D sprite. Using the sprite object works very well. Sprites that are outside of the area are cut off.
However, when I add text, everything drawn afterwards and the text itself is not cut off. PIX shows that a new DepthStencilState is set with the stencil buffer turned off as soon as draw text is called. The text is drawn by the same sprite object which is responsible for drawing other sprites.

The drawing is performed through the SlimDX.Direct3D10.Font.Draw method.

Is there a way to force DirectX not to change the state object? I use SlimDX, but according to its code it does not seem to be responsible for the state change.

Nico

Comment: Presumably as it's directx10 you are using a shader to draw this, and if it uses the effects framework I believe you can set depthstencil states in the effect. Perhaps the effect you are using is what is setting this, and you'd have to look in the Effect file not the program code?

Comment: Well, that could be possible. However, I use the Font class directly. So I have no access to the effect file. But the drawing is performed through the Sprite object and I assume, the Font class uses the same methods as for drawing simple sprites. So I doubt that it is a problem within the shader itself.

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/573166-dx10-id3dx10sprite-and-sampler-states/ discusses this sort of... and unfortunately seems to conclude that without some terrible hacks you can't avoid it setting the states to what it wants

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If drawing text is not working at all, I'll consider switching to DX11 using a custom sprite engine, since text was the only reason I stayed with DX10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're switching to D3D11, you might be interested in a font rendering library I've been working on porting to SlimDX (along with some other bits from the DirectX toolkit libraries that have been released over the past few months).

It's still in development, so no guarantees about anything, but you can find it here (SVN): http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Flite%2FSlimDX.Toolkit

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the meantime I have been starting to develop an engine on my own...